# Asp.net core web api put request returning error

Tags: api, asp.net-core, xamarin.forms

The following is working in Postman but not when a request is sent via Xamarin, is there something obvious that I am missing. My get request is working fine but I can't seem to 'put' data.

Core Api

```
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutTickets(int id, [FromBody] WorkTickets workTickets)
        {
  
            if (id != workTickets.Id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _context.Entry(workTickets).State = EntityState.Modified;

       
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return NoContent();
        }
```

Data

```
        private async void UploadLocalTickets()
        {
            try
            {

                WorkTickets workTickets = new WorkTickets()
                {
                    Id = 4426,
                    ActualWorkActivity = "test",
                };

                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                await DisplayAlert("Got Here", "Before Cloud", "OK");

                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(workTickets);

                var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                var result = await client.PutAsync("https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/apitickets/" + 4426, content);

                await DisplayAlert("Got Here", result.StatusCode.ToString(), "OK");

            }
            catch
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", "Caught", "OK");
            }

        }
```

Error is internal server error

Comment: an "Internal server error" means you need to look at your server logs for the details of the error

Comment: also, are you positive the json you submit in Postman matches the json you are submitting in C#?

Comment: Thank you for your comments @Jason 21. The issue was that my Mobile App was sending the whole WorkTickets class/model, with null values, even though I was only specifying two parameters (id and actualworkactivity). A rookie mistake on part (but I am rookie, so it is to be expected).

Comment: If your backend API is hosting on Azure App Service, to troubleshoot the `internal server error` issue, you can [enable diagnostics logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs) for your site, which will help collect logs for further troubleshooting.